# pass a function name as argument and then check correctness

Tags: python

I'm aware that I cann pass a function name as an argument to another function i.e

```
def fun_passed(a,b):
    #do something

def main_fun(arg,fun_passed):
    #do something



#call main_fun
first_fun =fun_passed
main_fun(1,first_fun)
```

Inside `main_fun` how can I make some checks.
For example, Based on the function i passed i want to set a variable

```
def main_fun(1,fun_passed):
     if fun_passed==first_fun:
             i=1
     else:
             i=10
```

I can't simply use `==` because i think that comparison doesn't make sense.
Thanks

Comment: What is the question? You can compare function objects for equality, it will return `True` if both variables refer to the same function. However, it will obviously return `False` if you compare references to two different functions that do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare functions for equality, but it's not going to check if the two functions do the exact same thing. Such a check is, in general, undecidable in the technical sense.

Instead, `f == g` simply returns true if both `f` and `g` return to the same underlying object (i.e., it's the same as `f is g`). This means that something as simple as `(lambda x: x) == (lambda x: x)` evaluates as `False`.

Comment: i was just interested in equality... I realized it was a dumb question. I'm sorry to have it posted

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `is` keyword:

```
def fct_a(a,b):
    #do something
    pass

def fct_b(a,b):
    #do something
    pass

def main_fun(fct):
    if fct is fct_a:
        print("fct is 'fct_a'")
    else:
        print("fct is not 'fct_a'")

main_fun(fct_a) # >> fct is 'fun_passed'
main_fun(fct_b) # >> fct is not 'fun_passed'
```

> For more about the differences between `is` and `==`, see **[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with functions, not a lambda, the function object has a variable `__name__` which shows the exact name of the original function. Here a simple example:

```
>>> def x():
...  return 0;
... 
>>> type(x)
<type 'function'>
>>> x.__name__
'x'
>>> y=x
>>> y.__name__
'x'
```

So in your case, it will be something like this

```
if fun_passed.__name__=="first_fun":
```